# Ionic audio player

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework

I have an application developed in ionic, and it needs to run existing audio in sdcard, I am using the audio tag html5 and in some cases works well but in others not:

It works:

```
file:///data/user/0/br.com.app/files/AUDIO_L2V4dGVybmFsL2F1ZGlvL21lZGlhLzEyMzM1NQ==.mp3
```

Does not work:

```
file:///data/user/0/br.com.app/files/AUDIO_L2RvY3VtZW50L3ByaW1hcnk6Y2x1c2JlL21lZGlhL2VudmlhZG9zL2F1ZGlvL2NsdXNiZV8xNDc2OTcwNDg3NDI3Lm1wMw==.mp3
```

any idea what might be happening?

Comment: you receive errors when not working?

Comment: no error is reported

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 audio tag can only play 3 type of audio, so extension can cause a problem. I see both of your files have mp3 (mpeg) extension, but it can be tricky/disturbing. So you should to be sure those files are valid.

An easy example when you have a wav file, but you rename the extension to mp3, the converter will "think" that is an mp3, but it is not true.

It might cause this. (In my case the cordova-media-plugin cause a similar issue, i thought if i set the extension to mp3, then the file will be mp3 too, but it won't)